# Observe not called with LiveData<PagedList>

Tags: android, datasource, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, pagedlist

I'm using the PagedList architectural components using a Room database and I am having trouble returning results to the observe method.

> Here is my Dao:

```
@Dao
interface WorkPackageStorageDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from workpackages where id = :id")
    fun getById(id: String): Workpackage

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(workpackage: Workpackage)

    @Query("Select * from workpackages WHERE id LIKE '%' || :searchString || '%' order by :orderBy")
    fun searchWorkpackages(searchString : String, orderBy : String) : DataSource.Factory<Int, Workpackage>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM workpackages")
    fun searchWorkPackgesTest() : List<Workpackage>

    @Query("Select * from workpackages WHERE id LIKE '%' || :searchString || '%' order by :orderBy")
    fun searchWorkPackgesTestQuery(searchString : String, orderBy : String) : List<Workpackage>

    @Query("DELETE from workpackages")
    fun deleteAll()

}
```

> My repository:

```
fun getAllWorkPackagesTestQuery() : List<Workpackage> {
    return workpackagesDao.searchWorkPackgesTestQuery("",SortedBy.WorkPackageNumber.type)
}

fun getAllWorkPackages() : DataSource.Factory<Int, Workpackage> {
    return getSortedAndSearchedWorkPackages("",
        SortedBy.WorkPackageNumber
    )
}

fun getSortedAndSearchedWorkPackages(searchString : String, sortBy: SortedBy) : DataSource.Factory<Int, Workpackage> {
    return workpackagesDao.searchWorkpackages(searchString,sortBy.type)
}
```

> Here is the method in my view model:

```
suspend fun fetchWorkPackagesInitial(
    workWeek: Configurations.AppWeek,
    pagingLimit: Int
) {

    coroutineScope {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val factory: DataSource.Factory<Int, Workpackage> =
                workPackageRepository.getAllWorkPackages()

            val pagedListBuilder =
                LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Workpackage>(factory, pagingLimit)
            workPackagesList = pagedListBuilder.build() 
            val list = workPackageRepository.getAllWorkPackagesTestQuery() //27 Items returned, query is fine. 
        }

    }
}
```

> Here is my fragment:

```
    mainViewModel.week.observe(this, Observer {
        it ?: return@Observer

        launch { workPackagesViewModel.fetchWorkPackagesInitial(it, PAGING_LIMIT) }

    })

    //Observe never called.  
    workPackagesViewModel.workPackagesList?.observe(this, Observer { wpList ->
        wpList ?: return@Observer

        adapter = WorkPackagesRecyclerAdapter(this)
        adapter.submitList(wpList)
        binding.workPackagesRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    })
```

As a test to my query, I've implemented:

```
val list = workPackageRepository.getAllWorkPackagesTestQuery()
```

which returns 27 items, so query is fine.  Am I setting up the the Dao wrong, the LivePagedListBuilder wrong?  Why is observe not called?

Comment: No reason to get the paged list datasource factory on an IO context.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting items because it's a `PagedList`. You need to trigger the load in order to obtain pages.

That is why giving the PagedList to a `PagedListAdapter` via `submitList` will eventually load the data.

You also don't need to manually invoke `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when you're using a `PagedListAdapter`, because the DiffUtil will handle that internally.

---

However, you should definitely be retrieving the `DataSource.Factory` and the `LivePagedListBuilder` and the `PagedList` on the UI thread (`Dispatcher.MAIN`), because threading is handled by the Paging lib's Room integration internally. Observing (and invoking `getItem(` on an unloaded element) will trigger the load, and the load will be executed asynchronously by the `DataSource` out of the box.

---

---

The way to use Paging is like this:

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val workPackageStorageDao: WorkPackageStorageDao
): ViewModel() {
    private val searchQuery: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData("")

    val workPackages: LiveData<PagedList<WorkPackage>> = Transformations.switchMap(searchQuery) { searchText ->
        val factory = workPackageStorageDao.searchWorkPackages(searchText, SortedBy.WorkPackageNumber)
        val pagedListBuilder = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, WorkPackage>(factory, pagingLimit)
        pagedListBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

Then in Fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // ... setup RecyclerView, etc

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java, viewModelFactory)
    viewModel.workPackages.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { pagedList ->
        adapter.submitList(pagedList)
    })
}
```

And in adapter:

```
class MyAdapter: PagedListAdapter<WorkPackage, MyAdapter.ViewHolder>(WorkPackage.ITEM_CALLBACK) {
     override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
         val workPackage = getItem(position)
         if(workPackage != null) {
             holder.bind(workPackage)
         }
     }
}
```

Long story short, you don't need coroutines here. Use the Paging Library and LiveData, and it will load on the correct threads.

Comment: It seems as though I'm getting the items, it's just that my observe is not being called.  See my edited question.

Comment: Trying to get the data source on Dispatchers.Main gives me an IllegalStateException, just BTW.

Comment: Yes it does, because you are running synchronous query right under it for no real reason (considering you're already using the Paging library right above it). If you don't call `getAllWorkPackagesTestQuery()`, it won't give you an ISE.

Comment: As I said, if you are using Paging (which is internally asynchronous), then don't call `getAllWorkPackagesTestQuery` which is synchronous.

Comment: workPackageRepository.getAllWorkPackages() is also synchronous.    So the problem remains.  Observe is not being called.

Comment: It's not synchronous. You get a `DataSource.Factory`, it doesn't do data loads right there and then.

Comment: if I comment out getAllWorkPackagesTestQuery() and put Dispatchers.Main, I still get illegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Comment: Okay, I will update my post with a specific answer on how this is supposed to look.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check if this resolves your issue.

Comment: seems to have fixed it.  Thanks so much!